# Would you tell me more about possessive?

Tags: possessives

It is a light on a car.
 Turn on the car light.
(that would be the light inside the car)

Or, you can use the possessive:
 Turn on the lights of your car.
(that would be the headlights (plural) on the outside of your car.)

Are you agree with these? if so, I am confused with them. Would anybody please explain them, in a simpler way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't think your options are technically incorrect (though "lights of your car" sounds strange), to me the use of "car light" itself is ambiguous and I doubt I would hear it said that way.

It would be better to say:

> Turn on the headlights.

And we say *dome light* for the interior light.

> Turn on the dome light.

It's understood you are referring to a car.

Comment: A health warning: in British English I have never heard the phrase "dome light" and would not understand it, so perhaps use something like "turn on the interior light".

Answer (score 0):

You can say, referring to the lights that are part of the car lighting system:

- the car's lights
- the lights of the car.

Genitive Case

You should still use the genetive case when talking about things that belong to other things.